# django url pass in context and post.id

Tags: django

views.py

```
class CheongsamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  
  def list(self, request):
        # set context
        context = {
        'url_update': 'item_update',
        }
        return Response(context)

  def update(self, request, pk):
        profile = get_object_or_404(itemModels, pk=pk)
        serializer = itemSerializers(profile, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print('status: status.Item Update')
            return redirect('item')
        else:
            print('status: status.Item Bad Update')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/', cheongsam_router_list, name='item'),
    path(r'item/product_edit/<str:pk>', cheongsam_router_detail, name='item_update')
]
```

create.html

```
<a href="{% url url_update post.id %}" class="btn btn-success" title="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
```

how do i pass in context variable and pk id at the same time in {% url %} ? both the context variable and object post has positive return so dont worry about it, but how do i put them into gether ?

if i just do {% url url_update %} or {% url 'item_update' post.id %} things work just fine.

error:

```
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: `{% url 'item_update' post.id %}` this is the right way

Comment: but i have to pass it as context variable url_update: 'item_update' for the reason, all my model CURD relate on one create.html page. is there a way i could pass in the context variable too ? or i am doing this all wrong ?